# how to link winsock in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake, winsock

I found only this strings

```
    find_library(WSOCK32_LIBRARY wsock32)
    find_library(WS2_32_LIBRARY ws2_32)
```

(i'm begginer in cmake)
how to link winsock2 (winsock?) in cmake?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Since these are both part of the Windows SDK, you shouldn't need to do a search for them.  Assuming you have the SDK installed, you can just do something like:

```
add_executable(MyExe main.cpp)
if(WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(MyExe wsock32 ws2_32)
endif()
```

Comment: indeed, you "shouldn't" need to do a search for them. However, in the off chance that you do... can CMAKE find them? For instance if you're using MinGW through a unusual compiler driver?

Comment: Yes, you can use [`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command:find_library) for each library to get the full path to it, then just include the result in your `target_link_libraries` call in place of the bare `wsock32` and/or `ws2_32`.